# Reading CPU temperature with assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu, temperature, msr

Hi i was wondering how could i read the CPU's temperature. I tried putting 0x19C in the ECX register and then calling rdmsr (to get IA32_THERM_STATUS) but the destination registries (EDX:EAX) are empty. I am using Pure64 operating system.

Comment: What CPU model do you have?  Are you running this in a VM or emulator?  It might not pass through any thermal stuff, even if your code is otherwise correct.

Comment: Model: 48
Model name: AMD A10-7850K Radeon R7, 12 Compute Cores 4C+8G. I am running this on QEMU.

Comment: QEMU might not pass through that MSR: https://www.redhat.com/archives/vfio-users/2016-June/msg00112.html indicates that it didn't in June 2016.  Does QEMU log about unimplemented MSRs?